# How to convert Facebook time zone to a custom string

Tags: php, facebook, timezone

I am working on facebook integration in my application.

Facebook returns users timezone in the format like for India its

```
5.5
```

But the existing timezones are saved in database in format

```
 +05:30
```

Any functions or algorithm suggestions for this conversion.

thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one is a bit long but it adds necessary preceding zeros etc if that's a requirement.

```
$num = -5.5;
$res = ($num < 0 ? '-' : '+') . (abs($num) < 10 ? '0' : '') . abs((int)$num) . ':';
// --> -05:
$mins = round((abs($num) - abs((int)$num)) * 60);
// --> 30
$res .= ($mins < 10 ? '0' : '') . $mins;
echo $res;
// -05:30
```

Comment: @edioe's suggestion was cleaner, though, if you don't mind the preceding zeros.

Answer (score 1):

Easy peasy (assume $a = 5.5):

```
$tz = ($a > 0 ? '+' : '-') . ((int) $a) . ':' . (($a - (int)$a)*60)
```

First bit gets you the - or + sign (left/right timezones), secondly casting $a to (int) you lose the fractional part and the third bit first gets the fractional part (I'm sure there's a php function for this but I come from C so basically: 5.5 - (int)5.5 = 5.5 - 5 = 0.5). The fractional part is expressed in hours (5.5 hours is 5 hours and 30 minutes) so basically 0.5 * 60 gets you the fractional part in minutes.

EDIT: Here's a cleaner (one-liner) version:

```
$time = sprintf("%+03d:%2d", (int)$a, abs($a-(int)$a)*60);
```

This one is pretty much the easiest. Thanks inhan for pointing out the abs() detail :)

Comment: You need an **abs** here: `abs((int) $a)` and another here: `abs(($a - (int)$a)*60)`.